# How to repeat an animation for the entire length of the composition in after effects?

Tags: animation, adobe-after-effects

The title says it all... How do I repeat a set of keyframes for the entirety of the composition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the exchange :')
You could select the keyframes: COPY then PASTE.

Is this what you need?

[image: select keyframes, copy, then paste]